# htaccess errors after upgrading Apache from 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I use 3 hosting for my websites, all of them have the same rules in htaccess.
One of the hosting was upgraded from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 and now I am getting errors spam and I don't know how to fix it without lossing the rule.

[Mon Jun 15 19:38:33.189697 2015] [rewrite:warn] [pid 236909] AH00665: RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored. (/home/*/public_html/*.com/.htaccess:31)

Here's the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly the issue. You just need to remove the [NC] as Dondi pointed out. Apache is **ignoring** it anyway as it says in the error message. There is nothing in the rule that will be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NoCase (`[NC]`) doesn't even make sense there as you're not matching anything. Just take it out.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```